# jQuery: How to refer to specific field in a JSON?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, reference, field

```
{
 "TEAM-9f0ca1c0-5d32-11e3-9cf7-782bcb4ce61a": {
   "queue": "RANKED_TEAM_5x5",
   "name": "Veigar's Scouts",
   "entries": [
      {
        "isHotStreak": false,
        "isFreshBlood": false,
  .... etc ...
```

I want to refer to this field: "TEAM-9f0ca1c0-5d32-11e3-9cf7-782bcb4ce61a", but this value is not a constant. How do I reference the specific field when the value is not constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're dealing with a deserialized object graph, not a JSON string.

You can loop through the property names (keys) of the top-level object using `for-in` and look for the one starting with `TEAM-`.

For example:

```
var obj = /* ... get the object; if you really have a string, use JSON.parse... */;
var key;
var value;
for (key in obj) {
    if (key.substring(0, 5) === "TEAM-") {
        value = obj[key];
        break;
    }
}
```

There I stopped on the first one I found. Note that the order in which the property names (keys) are visited is *not defined*, so if there may be more than one matching property name, you may need to add logic to choose one.

`for-in` enumerates (loops through) the enumerable properties of the object, giving you access to each property name in turn. In JavaScript, you can refer to a property in two ways: Either with literal notation (`foo.bar`), or with bracketed notation (`foo["bar"]`). In the latter case, the string name can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup. So since we have the property name as a string (in the variable `key`), we want to use bracketed notation when retrieving the value: `obj[key]`.